# angular material mat-expansion-panel animation is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have used the angular material mat expansion, but when it is being toggled it just pops without the animation.I have install angular animation and imported the browserAnimationModule, also hammerjs is installed as well.

here is my html code:

```
<mat-accordion class="m1">
  <mat-expansion-panel  class="m2">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header class="m3">
      <mat-panel-title class="m4">
        Personal data
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Type your name and age
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
```

when I click the toggle button I want the panel to expand with transition as it is here:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/bagrkbdegaj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts

Comment: where you add animation in your code?

Comment: It supposed to do the animation automatically

Comment: Can you add your module.ts or app.module.ts file, probably the imports from your component.ts file, and a complete mat-accordian? You don't have a closing tag in the above. If you copy/paste your code above into the example.html file in the stackblitz you link to, add some text to the expansion panel, and add the closing tag it works as designed.

Comment: Also, are you getting any errors if you open the developer tools panel in your browser?  If you're getting an error there, even if it's not related to your expansion panel, it could affect the rendering of that component.